# SQL: update specific rows based on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

So i have two tables as the following:

```
- T_Sample
ws_id|date|depth|number_l
     |    |     |
```

and

```
- T_Sample_value
ws_id|parameter|value
     |         |
```

I have some rows in the T_sample table, which have negative depth values and in the T_sample_value table they have some data; what i am trying to do is for these rows i would like to copy their data (present in T_sample_value) in the row which of T_sample which has 0 depth value.

I tried to do an update set query with subqueries but i get the error that the subquery does return multiple rows and cannot update the fields. What i tried looks pretty much like this:

```
UPDATE T_sample_value
SET T_sample_value.ws_id = (select blah blah where depth is <0)
WHERE T_sample_value.ws_id = (select blah blah where depth is = 0)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You would like to do a `update-join` like

```
UPDATE a
SET depth = b.value
FROM T_Sample a
JOIN T_Sample_value b
    ON a.ws_id = b.ws_id
WHERE a.depth = 0;
```

Comment: Sorry but you assumed that value is "depth". Actually, The T_sample_value table can contain thousands of rows with the same ws_id with different parameters and different values.

Comment: Ok, but now that you see the correct structure of an update-join, can you not adapt it to your needs?